# Removing an Imageview from View

Tags: android, android-view, android-viewbinder

I want to remove an imageview from a View (android.view.View)based on a codition.condition is the src of that image view.How can i remove an imageView from a view. please help

Comment: Hide the `ImageView`? Or remove the image from the `ImageView`? Try adding a few more specifics in the question.

Comment: If you want to remove imageview completely you use removeView(view) but if you want to hide the image view you can use ImageView.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE)

Answer (score 8):

By *remove* if you mean **hide** the ImageView, based on a particular condition, do something like this:

```
if (your_condition) {
    your_image_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
} else {
    your_image_view.setVisibility(View.VISISBLE);
}
```

If you need to remove the image currently set to the `ImageView`, do this in the `if ... else` above (based on the condition)

```
your_image_view.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);
```

OR

```
your_image_view.setImageBitmap(null);
```

If you need to *remove* the ImageView completely, call this, in the `if....else`, on the `ImageView's` *container*:

```
container.removeView(your_image_view);
```

Comment: thanks for the "android.R.color.transparent" trick  :)   [incidentally, we have someone here who doesn't like to accept good answers]

Answer (score 2):

To remove the `imageview`, use

```
if(condition) {
     imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

To make the `imageview` hide/invisible, use

```
if(condition) {
     imageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

To bring back the `imageview`, use

```
imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
LinearLayout linearLayout;
ImageView imageView;

if (condition) {
    linearLayout.removeView(imageView);
}
```

I'd need more information to provide a better answer.